# Credentials are Prompting for Send-MailMessage in PowerShell Script

Tags: windows, powershell, office365

I am pretty new to `PowerShell`.

I have done a `PowerShell` Script to Email certain files. I have noticed that every time I have run the script it prompts me for the Credential. I further learnt that I have to type the exact one unless it turns out and Error.

> I have setup the PowerShell Script to Task Scheduler in a Windows 10
>   Machine, but it still prompts despite logged in as a User having Local
>   Administrator Rights; I have also given Run with Highest Privileges
>   while creating the Task in Task Scheduler.
>
> I am trying to send from Office 365 service with a Active Directory
>   User in Azure.

My Objective is to avoid `PowerShell` Script to prompt for Credential. Please help me in this.

My Code:

```
#smtp Credential
$smtpKey = ConvertTo-SecureString "[My Password]" -AsPlainText -Force
$smtpCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("[MyUserName]", $smtpKey)

#Credentials are prompted here
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential smtpCredential -Attachments $filePath
```

**Update:**

As @Lee_Dailey pointed out in his answer, I have missed out `$` of the variable `smtpCredential` where I am calling out the `Send-MailMessage` task

Comment: you left off the `$` that tells PoSh "this is a variable". [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey such small mistakes cost me a lot! Thank you for pointing it out. Specify your comment as the answer, I will confirm the same. Thank you again!

Comment: Consider to use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1) to avoid lengthy commands where mistakes are overlooked easily.

Comment: @hiFI - done! glad that you got it working ... [*grin*]

Comment: @lotPings thank you very much for your response and `splatting` is definitely a valuable thing for me at this moment to look into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error is caused by the lack of a `$` to tell PoSh that `smtpCredential` is a variable. [*grin*]